# System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel in faulted state

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, master-page

When I try to deploy my SharePoint masterpage using Visual Studio I get the following error:

```
  “The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state”
```

I can imagine that this is not enough information for you to solve my issue, but I dont know what kind of info you need. So feel free to comment and I will provide what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may occur due to maxBuffersize in app.config
Try setting it to max value .. maxBufferSize="2147483647"